# SQL convert string to datetime

Tags: sql, string, date, datetime, converters

I have a column with string = '071113' and I need convert to type date like ='07/11/13'

I already used CAST('071113' as datetime) and CONVERT(datetime,'071113',103)
but the results is = '2007-11-13'

anyone?

Comment: What is the current Format is it DDMMYY or MMDDYY or YYMMDD ???

Comment: the current format is DDMMYY

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(10) = '071113'

SELECT  LEFT(@string, 2)+ '/'+ SUBSTRING(@string, 3,2)+ '/'+ RIGHT(@string, 2)

RESULT: 07/11/13
```